# php file upload script not working

Tags: php, mysql, upload

ive edited this question as it was pretty long!

im trying now to simply read the file info inputted to a input type="file" using php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['input-file'])){

$file_name = $_FILES['input-file']['name']; 
$file_size =$_FILES['input-file']['size']; 
$file_tmp =$_FILES['input-file']['tmp_name']; 
$file_type=$_FILES['input-file']['type'];

echo($file_name);
echo($file_size);
echo($file_tmp);
echo($file_type);
}
```

with a html form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="theform" method="post" action="image-upload-test2.php">
      <div id="container">
                <div id="input_template" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="file-container">
                        <div class="file-info"></div>
                        <div class="file-browse">Browse</div>
                        <div class="file-clear">X</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type='file' name="input-file" class="file-input-hidden" />
                </div>
      </div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

but I only ever get '0' echo'ed out, which ive managed to find out is the $file_size variable through elimination.

whats going wrong?

Comment: I would suggest that you just `var_dump` your `$_FILES['files']` before the loop and see what you get.

Comment: `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']` is not an array.

Comment: i get: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } when i var_dump $_FILES['files'], which means its empty right?

Comment: Following your edition, it seems to me that you do not need any `foreach`. You just need to do this: `$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];     $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'];`

Comment: using this, it doesnt work, but weirdly i echo the $file_name variable and it gives me 'Array'?

Comment: `print_r($file_name)` will show you what's in it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of on

```
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']
```

You should loop on

```
$_FILES['files']
```

or just

```
$_FILES
```

Comment: Yep. `foreach` only works on arrays, and `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just print_r/var_dump the $_FILES and see if something's inthere. Also, check if your HTML form has enctype="multipart/form-data" inthere.

Comment: ive done that and i get:
Array ( [input-file] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
which i believe error 4 means their is no file uploaded.. not sure whats going on